# Unity crashes as soon as it opens in the projects menu

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is the screenshot of the error I'm getting:

[image]

I already tried reinstalling it several times and my graphics card is working fine. Any ideas as to what could cause this?

Comment: Open the error.log file that was generated by Unity and paste the log into a code block.

Comment: You gave out your email address in the picture, it would be a good idea to blur it out in the future.

Comment: Maybe try to reinstall Unity, I had that happen to me before and reinstall helped

Comment: @serge : Let me quote the author: "I already tried reinstalling it several times"

Comment: What version are you on? I got that on the 2018.1b3 beta. Empty Projects work though